# Why is C++ formatting of long variable treating it like int?

Tags: c++, formatting

Working with a larger program, I found a fragment that is behaving strangely:

```
long L = 2500000000L;
fprintf( stderr, "L is %ld\n", L );
fflush( stderr );
```

Since the declaration of L is `long` and the format is `%ld`, I expected to see this print like "2500000000", but it actually prints

```
L is -1794967296
```

which is more what I'd expect from a format of `%d`.

However, if I change the format to `%uld` it prints 2500000000 correctly, although the compiler gives a warning that L should be declared `unsigned`.

Is this a bug in C++ formatting?  I'm using Eclipse + mingw on Windows, specifying dialect as c++11.

Comment: Perhaps you should add an assertion that size of `long` is sufficient to hold that number and it is not just 32 bit integer (in which case it will be out out of range of positive `long` numbers) (long being 32 bit is a common occasion on windows). `static_assert(8 == sizeof(L), "too small");`

Comment: A signed long can't hold that value, so you're seeing undefined behaviour manifested as wraparound in the first case and as your expected value in the second case.

Comment: see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types, `long` is usually 32-bits on windows, only 64-bit on 64-bit macos and Linux

Comment: It may also be a good idea to use direct list initialization to prevent potential narrowing `long L{2500000000L};`

Comment: I believe 2,500,000,000 (please check my count of 0's) is a little more than 2**31-1, the largest 32-bit signed integer, but should fit well within the range of a signed 64-bit integer.   The assertion suggested by  user7860670 did not fail.

Comment: Since you are using C++, use `std::cerr << "L is " << L << std::endl;`

Comment: Did you include the header stdio.h?

Answer (score 1):

`2'500'000'000` requires 32 bits to represent. On some machines (notably on Windows machines), `long` is 32 bits wide, and 1 bit is spared for the sign bit, so you are left with 31 bits, which is not enough. To fix this, you may use `unsigned long`, `long long` or `std::int64_t` depending on your needs.

Comment: The sign bit part is not true. Integers are usually represented in two's complement form, not sign-magnitude.

Comment: @sparik two's complement also requires 1 sign bit.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally edited your answer rather than mine :)

Comment: @eerorika with great (editing) power comes great responsibility :)

Answer (score 1):

The largest number that the `long` data type is required to be able to represent in C++ is 2'147'483'647. In other words, it must be a least 32 bits wide. 2'500'000'000 is outside of that range.

> Windows

Particularly in windows, `long` is a 32 bit number, and will not be able to represent 2'500'000'000.

> Is this a bug in C++ formatting?

Does not look like it would be.

> However, if I change the format to %uld it prints

If you do that, then the behaviour of the program will be undefined because that format specifier does not match the type of the argument. You must also change the type of the integer.

`unsigned long` is guaranteed to be able to represent 2'500'000'000 on all systems.

---

If you want to be able to represent 64 bit numbers, then the most portable choices are `long long`, `std::int_least64_t` and `std::int_fast64_t` all of which are guaranteed to be at least 64 bits.

Comment: I'll forward some of my coffee, if I get to make another comment.

Comment: In which ways `int_least64_t` is more preferable than `int_fast64_t`? Both appear to be at least 64 bits wide, and the latter may theoretically be faster.

Comment: Both `int_fast64_t` and `int_least64_t` lack length specifier in `printf`. `intmax_t` has one though.

Comment: @TedLyngmo `PRIdFAST64` and `PRIdLEAST64`.

Comment: @eerorika Ahhh... I forgot those :)

Comment: @Ayxan I added "fast" to the list. Whether one is more preferable depends on use case. I've never seen a system where they are different though, so it doesn't matter much.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yeah, they are difficult to find on a search engines if one doesn't know what to look for.

Comment: Totally slipped my mind. I haven' used the `printf` family of functions much in the last 20 years and only maybe once or twice have I ever used the width macros. :)

Answer (score -1):

There is no bug. This only means that the signed type long int in your system has the same width as the type int. As a result an object of the type long int is unable to represent such a positive number.

So instead of the type long int you could use the type long long int as for example

```
long long L = 2500000000;
fprintf( stderr, "L is %lld\n", L );
```

Pay attention to that it is better to exclude the suffix 'L' from the integer literal. The compiler itself will determine the type of the constant.

If an integer literal does not have a suffix then its type is determined from
these types relative to which type can represent the value

```
int int
long int
long long int
```

To check what signed integer type can accommodate such a constant run the following demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << 2500000000 << '\n';
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<int>::max() << '\n';
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<long>::max() << '\n';
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<long long>::max() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Another approach to determine what is the type of the constant is to use the standard class `std::is_same` declared in the header `<type_trais>`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <type_traits>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << 2500000000 << '\n';

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same<int, decltype( 2500000000 )>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same<long, decltype( 2500000000 )>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same<long long, decltype( 2500000000 )>::value << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

So if to use a call of printf that requires to specify a conversion specifier for an outputted object you could write

```
auto L = 2500000000;

if ( std::is_same<long, decltype( L )>::value )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "L is %ld\n", L );
}
else if ( std::is_same<long long, decltype( L )>::value )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "L is %lld\n", L );
}
```

Comment: *"This only means that the type long int in your system has the same width as the type int."* Nothing OP said indicates that.

Comment: @Ayxan No he did not say this. He said that the output was the same if to use the specifier %d.

Comment: Where did OP say that? I only see one part claiming they would expect such an output if they used `%d`

Comment: @Ayxan Yes. But he supported that the type long is wider than the type int. .